# Changing the stylesheet from index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement the ability for a *User* to change theme in my PhoneJS app (might as well be regular JS).

What I've tried:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link id="style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="red-stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function swapStyle(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('#style').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```

Where `sheet` is either `blue-stylesheet.css` or `red-stylesheet.css`, but I keep getting this error:

> Cannot 'setAttribute' for a reference that's undefined or null

So I'm guessing that I can't access the link from my index.html

This is my file structure:

```
views (folder)
  -> settings (folder)
    ->  settings.js (javascript)

index.html (html with the <link>)
```

Comment: Looks like `id` in `<link>` is not `#style` ..?

Comment: you're mixing js with jQuery `document.getElementById('style').setAttribute('href', sheet);` without `#`

Comment: My mistake. As @Pepo_rasta said, I was mixing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing stylesheet programatically not applying new style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247716/changing-stylesheet-programatically-not-applying-new-style)

Answer (score 3):

Your Javascript is just a little out. Theres no need for the `#` in the selector.

```
function swapStyle(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('style').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function swapStyle(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('style').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```

> The # before the id is only needed in JQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function swapStyle(sheet) {
   $('link[href="blue-stylesheet.css"]').attr('href','red-stylesheet.css');
}
```

or if you want you can wrap that in if statement like:

```
function swapStyle(sheet) {
    if($("link[rel='stylesheet']").attr("href") == "blue-stylesheet.css") {
        $('link[href="blue-stylesheet.css"]').attr('href','red-stylesheet.css');
    } else {
        $('link[href="red-stylesheet.css"]').attr('href','blue-stylesheet.css');
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].getElementsByTagName('link')[0].setAttribute('href', sheet);
```