# Changing stylesheet programatically not applying new style

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to implement the function for a *User* to change style of the application.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link id="style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="red-stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function swapStyle(sheet) {
    document.getElementById('style').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```

Where `sheet` = either `blue-stylesheet.css` or `red-stylesheet.css`.

It doesn't seem to work. My default theme is red, but when trying to change to blue, ALL styling seems to just disappear, and I can't get the red theme back.

How does one proceed?

**(PhoneJS/DevExtreme application)**

**Default when app is initiated**

[image]

**After pressing "Blue"**

[image]

Comment: Did you try: `document.getElementById('style').href = sheet;`

Comment: Link both [sheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet), and disable the one you don't need.

Comment: Duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247461/changing-the-stylesheet-from-index-html/32247728#32247728

Comment: Not duplicate, this is another matter.

Comment: @error404username_not_found How are those questions related???

Comment: @Detilium Notice, that you might need to reflow the page, before the new sheet will be applied.

Comment: @Teemu the problem is that DevExtreme haven't implemented a function to reload the view, but of course that out of the scope of this question

Comment: @Detilium DevExtreme? You can do it yourself, for example `document.body.className = document.body.className`. Though disabling/enabling sheets is recommenended instead of a violent change of the source.

Comment: ... and more, [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/href)  of a stylesheet is supposed to be read-only in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :

```
$('head>link[type="text/css"]').attr('href',sheet);
```

Comment: Did you read the question at all? Because, other than changing the selector, you posted what he's already doing.

Comment: I didn't really think it was necessary for me to post my entire index.html, but I have more `<link>` tags than just this one

Comment: $(' head>link[href="red-stylesheet.css"], head>link[href="blue-stylesheet.css"] ').attr('href',sheet);

Answer (score -2):

```
-----------Try This  -----
You use this code it's work

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
<script>
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Javascript Change StyleSheet Without Page Reload</h2>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('dark.css')">Dark Style Sheet</button>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('default.css')">Default Style Sheet</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing? I just separated my JS from my html

Comment: If you think it works, *explain how it works*, don't just throw code at the screen, *teach* people to understand what's going on.